# Media screen doesn't change with browser's resolution

Tags: html, css, screen, media-queries

I'm working with Media screens for the first time and They don't quite seem to be working the way they're supposed too....

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
```

all the css stylings within here and it shows up as this as it's supposed to.

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 321px) {
```

all css stylings that i place in here don't apply to the page when the width goes beyond 321 px. which isn't supposed to happen.... for example if i were to change any text color nothing would end up changing.

thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSS you write in this media query will be applied to the screen which has width less than `321px;`

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 321px) {
```

if you want to apply the same CSS when you resize it beyond `321px` then you need to increase the width as per your requirements -

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
```

You need to write Media Query to a class or element as -

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px){

body{
  font-size:20px;
  color:red;
}

}
```

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/MgSze/)

Comment: Nothing happens beyond 321px with this solution!

Comment: @user1775570 did you try resizing it?

Comment: @user1775570 you are writing Media Query wrong... copy paste the code I posted above and it will work :)

Comment: @user1775570 use only one width 700px remove the 321px